# How to get selected IndexPath from a stepper located inside a collection view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistepper

I have collection view that has stepper inside the collection view cell used to increase the number of product like the image below.

[image]

I need to know, when I click a stepper on a collection view cell. how do I know the `indexPath.item` of that collection view cell? so I can modify the data using the selected indexPath in the View controller?

so If I change the stepper in the second cell, I will always get indexPath.item = 1

I previously think that the `indexPath` will come from `didSelectItemAt` method below. but **it seems the `didSelectItemAt` method will not be triggered when I tap the stepper inside the collection view cell.**

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
```

so I think I can get indexPath from `cellForRowAt IndexPath` and using protocol delegate pattern. here is the method I made, **and I got the wrong indexPath**

So If I change the stepper in the second cell, I will NOT always get indexPath.item = 1 , It can be 2,3,0 etc.

here is the view controller code:

```
class WishListVC: UIViewController, ListProductCellDelegate {

    var products = [Product]()
    var selectedProduct : Product?

     // method from ListProductCellDelegate
    func stepperButtonDidTapped(at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath, stepperValue: Int) {

        // get selectedIndexPath
        // perform some action based on selectedIndexPath

    }
}

extension WishListVC : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return products.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: WishListStoryboardData.CollectionViewIdentifiers.productSliderCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as? ListProductCell else { return UICollectionViewCell()}


        cell.productData = products[indexPath.item]
        cell.indexPath = indexPath // I send the indexPath to the cell.
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        selectedProduct = products[indexPath.item]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: WishListStoryboardData.SegueIdentifiers.toProductVC.rawValue, sender: nil)
    }


}
```

and here is the code in the collection view cell:

```
protocol ListProductCellDelegate {
    func stepperButtonDidTapped( at selectedIndexPath: IndexPath, stepperValue: Int)
}

class ListProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    var delegate: ListProductCellDelegate?

    var productData : Product? {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stepperDidTapped(_ sender: GMStepper) {
        guard let indexPath = indexPath, let collectionView = collectionView else {return}
        self.delegate?.stepperButtonDidTapped(at: indexPath, stepperValue: Int(sender.value))
    }


    func updateUI() {
        // update the UI in cell.
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add stepper tag value = indexPath.row and check on the basis of stepper tag value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding `tag` property to the stepper. So when you click on the stepper you can listen to its selector and determine which stepper was called. The tag value should be same as the item index.

Something like this

```
cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
```

Above code should go inside the cellForRowAt delegate function.

and then when user taps on the stepper call a function and check the tag value

Something like this

```
func stepperClicked(sender) {
    //check sender.tag value
    //Do something here with the tag value
}
```

Comment: it seems the indexPath.row still give random int value if I click a cell

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by random value?

Answer (score 2):

In Swift a **callback closure** is probably the most efficient solution. It's independent of index paths, tags, view hierarchy *math* and protocols.

In the cell add a `callback` property which passes the stepper instance. Delete both `indexPath` and `delegate`. The protocol is not needed at all.

In the `IBAction` call `callback` and pass the stepper instance

```
class ListProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var callback: ((GMStepper) -> Void)?

    var productData : Product? {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stepperDidTapped(_ sender: GMStepper) {
        callback?(sender)
    }


    func updateUI() {
        // update the UI in cell.
    }
}
```

In the controller in `cellForItemAt` set the closure and handle the callback. The index path is captured in the method.

And don't `guard` cells. Force unwrap it. The code must not crash. If it does it reveals a **design** mistake. With the `guard` way the table view would display nothing and you don't know why.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: WishListStoryboardData.CollectionViewIdentifiers.productSliderCell.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! ListProductCell
    cell.productData = products[indexPath.item]
    cell.callback = { stepper in 
       // handle the callback
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I can find, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have the stepper because it is the `sender` in your action method. The stepper has a superview which is the cell (you might have to walk up more than one superview to reach the cell). Once you have the cell you can call `indexPath(for:)` to get the index path. Done.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618094-indexpath