# Get indexPath from cell after Stepper changed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Simple table. Cell contains 3 elements: Name label, count label, stepper. Im trying to change a count value by increment-decrement stepper object. How can i get access to indexPath to this exact cell? 
Who should be the sender, UIStepper or UITableViewCell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].name
    cell.textField.text = String(items[indexPath.row].count)


    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}

@IBAction func stepperChanged (_ sender:UIStepper){        

}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737450/how-to-get-selected-indexpath-from-a-stepper-located-inside-a-collection-view-ce/53738915#53738915

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, the stepper is in the cell. The cell should handle the stepper events. The cell class should provide a delegate/protocol pattern or it should provide a closure property. The cell would call the delegate or closure when the stepper changes. The cell and the new value would be arguments in the delegate method/closure.

The view controller (or whatever class contains the `cellForRowAt` method) would configure the cell by setting itself as the delegate and implementing the delegate protocol method or by assigning a closure to the closure property.

When the delegate method or closure is called, the cell is obtained as one of the parameters. `self.tableView.indexPath(for:)` can be used, passing in the cell, to get the cell's index path allowing you to properly update the data model with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

As your stepper is in UITableViewCell class,you should have action of Stepper in your table view cell class, you should use protocol to get the indexPath of the stepper value changed in UITableViewCell.
here is complete example on how to use it.

first step is to have protocol in your ItemTableViewCell. Your TableViewCell class will look like this.

```
import UIKit
protocol StepperDelegate: class {
    func stepperDidChange( inCell : UITableViewCell)

}
class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var delegate: StepperDelegate?
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func stepperChanged (_ sender:UIStepper){
    if let stepperDelegate = self.delegate {
        stepperDelegate.stepperDidChange(inCell: self)
    }
}

}
```

you should then set delegate to your view controller class in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and then implement this delegate in view controller.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].name
    cell.textField.text = String(items[indexPath.row].count)
    return cell
}
```

and implement this delegate in ViewController

```
extension ViewController : StepperDelegate {
func stepperDidChange(inCell: UITableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: inCell)
    //here you have the indexPath of the stepper pressed in UItableViewCell

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
There are many ways to do the same. I am posting the easiest way to achieve this. In your method add a few lines of code.


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell
cell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].name
cell.textField.text = String(items[indexPath.row].count)
cell.stepper.tag = indexPath
cell.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperBtnAction(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
// Configure the cell...
return cell
```

}

```
//MARK :- Stepper Button Action
@objc func stepperBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = sender.tag // This will give you the indexPath
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ItemTableViewCell
}
```